# Error Handling in PowerBI RestAPIs in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, event-handling, powerbi

I'm trying to make an automated email system for whenever my PowerBI rest APIs encounter an error in PowerShell.  Basically, my PowerBI RestAPI will sometimes give the following error:

[image]

And whenever, it gives this error, I want my PowerShell script to send me an email.  I am currently testing the following code, but it does not work at all. Ideally when the error occurs for the below code, it should print "Error". Instead, it just prints the error and stops.  I am wondering if anyone has any experience in error handling using PowerBI rest APIs.

```
$User = "email@hotmail.com"
$PW = "mypw"

$SecPasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $PW -AsPlainText -Force
$myCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($User,$SecPasswd)

Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -Credential $myCred

# 2. Refresh Dataset
try{
Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url "datasets/2-cdaf123fa5/refreshes" -Method Post -Body '{"notifyOption": "MailOnFailure"}'
}

# 3. Check if there is an error
catch {
            $emailSmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
            $emailSmtpServerPort = "587"
            $emailSmtpUser = "email@gmail.com"
            $emailSmtpPass = "password"

            $emailFrom = "email@gmail.com"
            $emailTo = "email@gmail.com"

            $emailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage( $emailFrom , $emailTo )
            $emailMessage.Subject = "subject" 
            $emailMessage.Body = "body"

            $SMTPClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient( $emailSmtpServer , $emailSmtpServerPort )
            $SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $True
            $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential( $emailSmtpUser , $emailSmtpPass );
            $SMTPClient.Send( $emailMessage )
    }
```

Comment: Without code I can only guess the correct way. This is the best instructions on the internet. https://leanpub.com/thebigbookofpowershellerrorhandling/read

Comment: Hi Aaron, I have provided my code.  But I'm not sure if that would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few ways to handle this.  You are have a non-terminating error.  You can go back to the link above and search for the qoutes below if my solution does not fit your needs.

> Try/Catch/Finally The Try/Catch/Finally statements, added in
>   PowerShell 2.0, are the preferred way of handling terminating errors.
>   They cannot be used to handle non-terminating errors, unless you force
>   those errors to become terminating errors with ErrorAction or
>   $ErrorActionPreference set to Stop.
>
> A value of Stop causes non-terminating errors to be treated as
>   terminating errors instead, immediately halting the Cmdlet’s
>   execution. This also enables you to intercept those errors in a
>   Try/Catch or Trap statement, as described later in this section.

At the top of your script add

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome that did it.